# Replacing backslash characters with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have this piece of code:

```
$data = 'Test\\vv testing\\vv';
        $data = preg_replace('/(\\vv)/', '\test', $data);
```

Yet after the preg_replace, $data is still Test\vv testing\vv.

I don't understand why, on any regex tester, the regex matches the part of the string I want to replace, which are the '\v' parts.

Comment: why preg replace when you can use `str_replace('\\vv', '\test', $data);` ?

Comment: Because I need it for something else that's bigger. I only took this tiny part of the regex I know causes a problem.

Comment: Then can you show us the "bigger" `$data` ? Just curiosity, im pretty sure you can make it without regex :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A backslash character (`\`) is considered to be an escape character by both PHP's parser and the regular expression engine (PCRE). If you write a single backslash character, it will be considered as an escape character by PHP parser. If you write two backslashes, it will be interpreted as a literal backslash by PHP's parser. But when used in a regular expression, the regular expression engine also picks it up as an escape character.

So in order to match a literal backslash in PHP regex, you need to write four slashes: `\\\\`:

From the [PHP manual documentation on *Escape Sequences*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> Single and double quoted PHP strings have special meaning of backslash. Thus if `\` has to be matched with a regular expression `\\`, then `"\\\\"` or `'\\\\'` must be used in PHP code.

Your code should be:

```
$data = preg_replace('/(\\\\vv)/', '\replaced', $data);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/172691)

---

Note: As Bob0t correctly said in the comments, you do *not* need `preg_replace()` for this  task since it only involves plain strings and not patterns. A plain 'ol [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) should suffice:

```
$data = str_replace('\\vv', '\test', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use:

```
$re = "/\\\\vv/"; 
$str = "Test\\vv testing\\vv"; 
$subst = '\\replaced'; 
 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

In PHP you need to use `\\\\` to match a single backslash `\`. It is because 1st escapig is for PHP string and 2nd escaping is for underlying PCRE regex engine.

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pS4qO0/1)